# Sendgrid Enforced TLS and API responses on

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

I was reading [this](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/settings-enforced-tls/retrieve-current-enforced-tls-settings):

> You can optionally choose to enforce TLS encryption, meaning that if the recipient's inbox provider does not accept the TLS encryption, Twilio SendGrid drops the message and sends a block event with “TLS required but not supported” as the description.

If my service uses the Node SDK, with an API key with TLS enforced and sending an email via **`POST`** `/v3/mail/send` and the email gets dropped, does the call result in a 500 or 400 error on the SDK?

Tried looking through docs and it wasn't clear to me.  I was going to set up a STMP relay to test this out but wanted to check here first